# What are some guidelines to keep in mind when selecting members of one's PhD committee?

Tags: phd, thesis-committee

Selecting members of one's PhD committee is an important part of a PhD student's academic  development. Committee members can have considerable influence on a student's PhD program, such as determining what topics are on the student's prelims exams. However, sound advice on this process can be hard to find.

*What are some guidelines to keep in mind when selecting members of one's PhD committee?*

(This should be a generalized question useful for many different student-selected committee systems)

Comment: [The Thesis Committee - The PHD Movie 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbT4G8XR2io) is relevant here ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are some general guidelines for choosing members of a PhD committee:

- **They should have some enthusiasm for the work that you do.** If they're not invested in seeing you succeed, you won't get as much utility out of that committee member as someone else who might not be as knowledgeable, but is more committed.
- **They should have the time to be on your committee.** If they're extremely busy, then it doesn't help to have them on a committee, because it will be difficult for them to attend the meetings—or it will make scheduling the meetings a nightmare.
- **They should not have conflicts with either you or your advisor.** A thesis committee is already a somewhat political body. There's no need to add extra politics to the situation by having interpersonal or professional conflicts before the committee even begins to meet!
- **Collectively, there should not be a power "imbalance."** If your advisor is a new assistant professor, don't overload the committee with a bunch of full professors holding named chairs, and *vice versa*.

When they will set preliminary exams, there's the additional qualification of:

- The committee members should be familiar enough with your area that they know what it might make sense to test you on, but not *so* familiar with your work that they turn it into a "gotcha" game.

Answer (score 6):

aeismail's post is very good, and just to add another few:

- How difficult of a committee member are they? Some people will ask you to do far more work than others, and they typically have a reputation as such. It's worth trying to find that out and saving yourself the headache.
- Many universities allow one or two committee members from outside the university. If there is a particular subject matter expert you would like to consult, feel free to ask them to serve on your committee... it  can help you build a relationship with them and get their feedback on your research.